# Error installing xcache '[processor.lo] Error 1'

Tags: php, nginx, php-fpm, xcache

I am trying to get xcache 1.3.2 installed on my centos 5.8final (64bit) machine. It's running nginx 1.1.13 and php 5.4.0.

This is the output of `./configure --enable-xcache --with-php-config=/opt/php/bin/php-config`

http://pastebin.com/YWVyna1S

Seems to be going OK, but when i want to `make` it, it shows this error: make: `*** [processor.lo] Error 1`

Full output here of `make`.

http://pastebin.com/Sz1k2Jzq

Any idea how to resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XCache currently does not support PHP 5.4.0 as the API changed, latest supported is 5.3.10.

http://xcache.lighttpd.net/ticket/271

On a side note. I also can't APC to compile on PHP 5.4.0, so giving it a bit of time before you upgrade might be a good idea.

Comment: Ok that makes sense. I will revert back to 5.3.9

Comment: You should revert to 5.3.10. 5.3.9 has a security issue.